# Windows cmd docker command piping

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, cmd

I found this instruction on piping commands in Windows CMD:

> The "pipe" redirects the output of a program or command to a second program or command.
>
> Syntax:
>
> ```
> Command1 | Command2
> ```

[[Source](http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/DOS7/pipes.html)] (at the very bottom)

Yet `docker ps -aq | docker start` or any similar combination just returns errors.

The only working combination to start all stopped container works in PowerShell.

```
docker start $(docker ps -a -q -f "status=exited")
```

Comment: Powershell isn't quite the same as cmd. What errors, exactly, do you get?

Comment: Yeap, I understand its just that I do most of my work through CMD, turning on powershell each time I need docker seems cumbersome. I get '"dokcer start" requires at least 1 argument.' -> docker ps -aq | docker start

Comment: The error message suggests that the docker program does not read from stdin and must have explicit command line parameters specified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [pipe into docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38511835/1630171) (`-i`), but you can't pipe arguments to the docker command itself.

In PowerShell use a loop for starting a list of stopped containers:

```
docker ps -a -q -f "status=exited" | ForEach-Object { docker start $_ }
```

In CMD use a loop for starting a list of stopped containers:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('docker ps -a -q -f "status=exited"') do docker start %i
```

Comment: PowerSheel is no problem :) I am looking for a solution in windows CMD.