# docker pg_restore stdin with powershell core

Tags: docker, powershell

I try to translate this command with Powershell Core

```
docker run --rm -e PGPASSWORD=$Env:PGPASSWORD postgres:14.2 pg_restore --clean -d db -h mydb.com -U sa --format=custom < pg.dump
```

And I have this error

> The '<' operator is reserved for future use.

I've tried many things like

```
echo pg.dump | docker run --rm -e PGPASSWORD=$Env:PGPASSWORD postgres:14.2 pg_restore --clean -d db -h mydb.com -U sa --format=custom
```

> pg_restore: error: could not read from input file: end of file

```
echo pg.dump | docker run --rm -e -it PGPASSWORD=$Env:PGPASSWORD postgres:14.2 pg_restore --clean -d db -h mydb.com -U sa --format=custom
```

> the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'

I can't find how to use the stdin operator with Powershell Core

Answer (score 0):

Try to change sequence of your actions. Run container -> Copy backup file into container -> Run command `pg_restore`

Here is an algorithm (not the working code) to execute in powershell. Note that `docker cp` may work only with container id. You can get it if you parse it via `docker ps | Select-String -Pattern "my_postgres"`

```
Set-Location "C:\postgres_backup"
Write-Output "Starting postgres container"
docker run --rm --name=my_postgres --env PGPASSWORD=$Env:PGPASSWORD postgres:14.2

Write-Output "Copying backup to container"
docker cp ./pg.dump my_postgres:/pg.dump

Write-Output "Execute something in postgres container"
docker exec -i $my_postgres pg_restore --clean -d db -h mydb.com -U sa --format=custom -1 pg.dump
```

Comment: Thanks, I was already doing something like that before. What I'm looking for is how to do the same one liner in powershell core.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by *Siarhei Kavaleuski*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57650210/3366563) I managed to find a way. Strange one, but it worked for me and I hope will work for you.

I'll provide a command for `docker compose` and `exec`. But I think you can adapt the idea for your case (`docker run` command). *It would be nice, if your share with community your final result.*

```
Start-Process pwsh -ArgumentList "-Command `"docker compose exec -T db sh -c 'pg_restore --username `$POSTGRES_USER --dbname `$SQL_DATABASE'`"" -RedirectStandardInput "D:\path\to\db.dump" -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

###### KEY NOTES

- We use `sh -c 'pg_restore ...'`  in order to use environment variables of the 'db' container *(specified in compose file, for example)*.
  And `sh` not `bash` because `sh` works even on Alpine.
- We add `-T` option after `exec` to [disable automatic TTY allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38511835). **Note**, that *not* `-t` (smaller)
- We use the backtick character (`), which is the [PowerShell escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2#double-quoted-strings).
- We can't use `Get-Content "D:\path\to\db.dump" | docker compose exec -T db ...` here, because a `*.dump` file is most often not a text file. Hence, we have resort to `-RedirectStandardInput`